# eclipse jobs with views problem?

Tags: eclipse, view, jobs, rcp

I am writting a manager program in a rcp way with eclipse, so I want to create a "*command center*" job which will run until the game is over. It'll get input from views, editors or via socket channel which is another job to get remote servers'/clients' request, and vice versa. But I do not know how to do it? So as a summary I have two problem:

1. How a job communicate with a ui part of eclipse?
2. How a job communicate with another?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think, that an Eclipse Job is well-suited for this purpose, because jobs are basically used as elementary, but long tasks.

I would create something you do require as a controller/"command center" view, that can be used by the user to control the game. In this case, the view can communicate with the internal model e.g. using the Data Binding API, and with other views using the Selection service.

Or if you would like to control your application automatically in the background, you could create different event listeners, that can create small jobs, that read/write the data model of the application.

Comment: We can use IpropertyChangeListener to do this work, see this link below:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecllink/